# Coffeescript static inheritance of child classes

Tags: coffeescript

This works :

```
class Foo 
  class @_Bar 
    @narf = ''
    @point : ->
      @narf = 'what'

  class @_Baz extends @_Bar 
    @point : ->
      @narf = 'woo'
      super()
```

This does not

```
class Foo 
  class @_Bar 
    @narf = ''
    @point = ->
      @narf = 'what'

  class @_Baz extends @_Bar 
    @point = ->
      @narf = 'woo'
      super()
```

running `Foo._Baz.point()` will throw and error.

---

Please someone explain what is going on here.

Comment: In addition to the bug report that Trevor created,   https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1598 is the issue that added `super` support to static methods (some 2 years ago).

Comment: Participating there now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of fixes now on github.  https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/3232

Currently the node tree for a `@foo=` method is different from that of a `@foo:` method.  Because of that, a node created with `=` is never passed to the `Class addParameters` method, and is never flagged as `static`.

One solution, which will probably be accepted, makes sure both forms produce the same node tree.

The one I contributed https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/3232#issuecomment-28316501 
adds a method to `nodes.coffee class Class`. This method is a stripped down version of `addParameters`, and specifically checks a `=` node tree.

If you need a fix in your own Coffee compiler, modify your `src/coffee-script/nodes.coffee` file, compile it, and put the resulting `node.js` in the `lib` directory (or use the `cake build`).

Comment: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/pull/3237/files is the current modification.  The part involving `looksStatic` can be added to the 1.6.3 `nodes.coffee`.  I haven't played with the part involving `METHOD_DEF` which addresses a different issue.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like a bug in the compiler to me. Writing

```
class X
  @classMethod: ->
```

and

```
class X
  @classMethod = ->
```

should be equivalent, yet `super` compiles differently across the two methods. In the first, it compiles correctly:

```
X.__super__.constructor.classMethod.apply(this, arguments);
```

In the second, it compiles as if `classMethod` were an instance method:

```
X.__super__.classMethod.apply(this, arguments);
```

Comment: Really, you think its a bug? I thought is was deliberate, and that I was simply not understanding the intent.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
class Foo 
  class @_Bar 
    @narf = ''
    point : ->
      @narf = 'what'

  class @_Baz extends @_Bar 
    @point = ->
      @narf = 'woo'
      super()

alert Foo._Baz.point()  # 'what'
alert new Foo._Bar().point() # 'what'
```

That is, the compiled `@point=` `super` ends up pointing to the instance `point:`.  Its JS is: `_Baz.__super__.point.call(this)`, which is `_Bar.prototype.point.call(this)`.  (`extends` defines: `child.__super__ = parent.prototype`).

It's clear from past Coffeescript changes that `@point:` is the intended syntax for static (class) methods (and used that way in the compiler itself).

Comment: That makes no sense. `point : ->` attaches as `Foo.prototype.point` so the static method does not access it.

Comment: Try it.  I'm pointing out what Coffeescript does, not I think it should do.

Comment: Actually `point : ->` attaches as `Foo._Bar.prototype.point`.

Comment: you are right `Foo._Bar.prototype.point` is the place it attaches, but your answer  " That is, the @point= super points to point: " is still wrong because prototype is not static, its instance.

Comment: Your original  code throws an error because `Foo._Bar.prototype.point` is undefined.  Mine works because that 'instance' method is defined.  The crossover between `static` to `instance` is not what you intended, but that is, in effect, what the Javascript code does.

Comment: Run `coffee -n` on your code samples.  You'll see that `@point:` and `@point=` produce different node trees.

Comment: Right but thats the problem. If you change your answer from `point : ->` to `@point : ->` I will remove the downvote.